# Finding the number of pairs with given GCD and LCM (proof)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In order to find the number of pairs with a given $GCD$ and $LCM$, I find the number $n$ of prime factors in $\frac{LCM}{GCD}$. The number of pairs is equal to $2^n$.

Example: $GCD=2$ and $LCM=120$

$\frac{LCM}{GCD} = 60 = 2^2 * 5 * 3$ therefore we have $2^3$ (we have 3 prime factors) pairs.

Could you please explain to me why this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly one of the two members of the pair must be divisible by $2^3$ --- that's a choice of 2 options.

Exactly one of the two numbers must be divisible by 3. Two more options.

Exactly one of the two numbers must be divisible by 5. Two more options.

So, 2 options for each of 3 primes, so $2^3$ options all told.

I'm assuming these are ordered pairs we are discussing.

Comment: It's only the prime factors in that quotient that get to be distributed between the two numbers in the ordered pair. If, say, 7 appears to the same power in both LCM and GCD, then both numbers in the pair must be divisible by exactly that power of 7, so only one option for assigning powers of 7.

Comment: You have been of great help, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b)=2$ and $[a,b]=120$

Again let $\displaystyle\frac aA=\frac bB=2\implies (2A,2B)=2\iff (A,B)=1 $ and $[2A,2B]=120\iff [A,B]=60\implies A\cdot B=60$

As $60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5,$

So, between $A,B$ one can have $2^2$ as factor, the other will have $1$ as factor

Similarly for $3$ and $5$